# listening to child window messages in win32

Tags: winapi

I have a blank window created by my own application in C++. What I do is I bring in another window of some entirely different application and make it a child window of this. It can by skype, firefox, anything.

What I want to do is I want to listen to the messages received by this new window that is now my child window. Unfortunately I don't get the messages through my own WndProc. It is probably doable through Hooks, is there any other simpler way of listening to the child window messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since windows have thread affinity and since messages are delivered to windows, you need your code in the thread associated with the window. That implies hooks.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I think the window being parented would not help with the fact that the window belongs to a different process. I'd guess this still needs a global hook.

Comment: @sertac can you even parent a window into another process?

Comment: Yep, no problem with that, just be careful not to end the parenting window's process before the child's.

Comment: @sertac completely missed the cross process aspect. Updated. Thanks. I'll pay you back!

Comment: Nothing changes just because you called SetParent().  The window procedure still lives in another process.  A WH_CALLWNDPROC hook with an injectable DLL is required.